# Chromecast — Broken DRM playback

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

## context

- the content being cast is a video stream with audio
- this error happens in all devices, chrome, android and ios
- DRM is playready

## problem

When casting a DRM content after 5~15m of reproduction it produces an error, this is the output from the receiver console:

```
onPause : 16:39:02 player.js:16
setState("paused") : 16:39:02 player.js:16
onStalled : 16:39:06 player.js:16
setState("buffering") : 16:39:06 player.js:16
onBuffering : 16:39:06 player.js:16
setState("buffering") : 16:39:06 player.js:16
onStalled : 16:39:09 player.js:16
setState("buffering") : 16:39:09 player.js:16
9
Uncaught Error: [goog.net.XhrIo] Object is active with another request=https://drm-license.domain.com; newUri=https://drm-license.domain.com media_player.js:50
H.send media_player.js:50
h.yb media_player.js:101
h.Me
```

Note: the `drm-license.domain.com` is a fake url.

This is the [manifest content](http://hastebin.com/limusoboge.xml).

I'm not sure if this is enough info to understand the possible problem, please comment if there is something relevant that should be added.

Comment: There's a lot of missing info...  What's the content?  Audio file?  Video?  What application are you streaming?  Where is the DRM from (iTunes, etc.)?

Comment: Is this an issue with only a specific stream that you have?

Comment: It would be good if you turned on logging to add to your results.  cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(cast.receiver.LoggerLevel.DEBUG);
cast.player.api.setLoggerLevel(cast.player.api.LoggerLevel.DEBUG);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved since the last [Chromecast update](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes) at **March 10, 2014**